# Why socket.join doesn't work in connection.query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I think I have found a bug. If I put socket.join(/*any room here*/) inside connection.query function it won't simply join that room. Interesting fact is that console.log works:

```
function registerInRoom (user, room) {
    var post_room = {Users_user_id: user, Rooms_room_id: room, ur_id: undefined};
    connection.query('INSERT INTO mydb.users_has_rooms SET ?', post_room, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        socket.room = room;
        console.log("joined room");
        socket.join("Room 1");
    });

};//registerInRoom
```

And here is working code:

```
function registerInRoom (user, room) {
    var post_room = {Users_user_id: user, Rooms_room_id: room, ur_id: undefined};
    connection.query('INSERT INTO mydb.users_has_rooms SET ?', post_room, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        socket.room = room;
        console.log("joined room");
    });
    socket.join("Room 1");
};//registerInRoom
```

My question is... What am I doing wrong in my thinking process?

Comment: I believe you have a lexical scope issue as the socket doesn't necessarily exist within the local of that query and because it's not able to access it, it remains undefined thus not doing anything.

Comment: In node debugger it says: 
`socket.io:socket joining room 1 +101ms
socket.io:socket joined room 1`

and after sending message in this room socket emits event "send message" and dispatches it but client doesn't receives packet "new message" while in second case it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problems were caused by overwriting original socket.id what shouldn't be ever done:

```
socket.id = result.insertId;
```